# SQL Query, obtain maximum with no duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, Player and Shot. There is a 1 to many relationship between Player and Shot. I want to get some player information, like Email, FirstName, and LastName, along with a player's top shot information, which contains various parts- CalculatedScore, AccuracyScore, DistanceScore, and TimeScore. CalculatedScore is the most important value. All the others are components of that score.

Here's my best effort:

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
select s_max.PlayerId as playerId_max, s_max.TopScore, s.PlayerId, p.FirstName,
p.LastName, s.CalculatedScore, s.AccuracyScore, s.TimeScore, s.DistanceScore from Player p
inner join Shot s on s.PlayerId = p.Id
inner join (
    select distinct MAX(CalculatedScore) over (partition by PlayerId) as TopScore,
     PlayerId from Shot s2  
) s_max on s.PlayerId = s_max.PlayerId and s.CalculatedScore = s_max.TopScore
order by PlayerId desc
```

This is almost identical to what I need, but it returns each row that ties for the top score. Getting it to return one row instead is surprisingly frustrating.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: How would you choose which row it returns?

Comment: It would be arbitrary, as long as the CalculatedScore is the max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a good case to use `outer/cross apply`.This should perform better than using window function, especially if you `Player` table has small number of rows:

```
select
    p.Id, p.FirstName, p.LastName,
    s.CalculatedScore, s.AccuracyScore, s.TimeScore, s.DistanceScore
from Player as p
    outer apply (
        select top 1 s.*
        from Shot as s
        where s.PlayerId = p.Id
        order by s.CalculatedScore desc
    ) as s
```

here's [**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/54100/1) with examples, you can check performance.

Comment: This is basically a correlated subquery, what makes you think that this should perform better than window functions?. As I see it, this will need to scan the `Shot` table once per row on `Player`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, this is what you want:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PlayerId 
                                 ORDER BY CalculatedScore DESC)
    FROM Shot
)
SELECT  A.PlayerId as playerId_max, 
        B.TopScore, 
        A.FirstName,
        A.LastName, 
        B.CalculatedScore, 
        B.AccuracyScore, 
        B.TimeScore, 
        B.DistanceScore
FROM Player A
INNER JOIN CTE B
    ON A.PlayerId = B.PlayerId
WHERE B.RN = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` instead (to get one row).  Also, you don't need an additional join when using window functions:

```
select s.PlayerId , s.TopScore, s.PlayerId, p.FirstName,
       p.LastName, s.CalculatedScore, s.AccuracyScore, s.TimeScore, s.DistanceScore
from Player p inner join
     (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by s.PleryId order by CalculatedScore desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from Shot s
     ) s
     on s.PlayerId = p.Id and seqnum = 1
order by s.PlayerId desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (select   s_max.PlayerId as playerId_max
             , s_max.TopScore
             , s.PlayerId
             , p.FirstName
             , p.LastName
             , s.CalculatedScore
             , s.AccuracyScore
             , s.TimeScore
             , s.DistanceScore
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PlayerID ORDER BY CalculatedScore DESC)'RowRank'
        from Player p
        inner join Shot s 
            on s.PlayerId = p.Id
        order by PlayerId desc
        )sub
WHERE RowRank = 1
```